# how to get the value of an attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the attributes values of an element.

My code is as follows:

```
 var vid=$('div.selected a');
 var dataid=$(vid).data('vid');
 var dataalid=$(vid).data('alid');
```

And HTML

```
 <div class="vblock" id="selected">
 <a class="video" data-alid="4" data-vid="4" href="resources/videos/xyz4.mp4">
```

I need to get the value of `data-alid` and `data-vid` of `<a>` tag. Please anyone help me....

Comment: That seems correct, what's not working?

Comment: When i run the code it returns undefined..

Comment: @James i think James Allardice answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with what you have, but you've made a simple mistake. Your markup shows that the `div` has an ID of "selected", not a class, so you need to use an ID selector:

```
var vid=$('#selected a');
```

Notice that I've removed the `div` from the selector. That's because ID values must be unique within a document and there is therefore no need to qualify them.

Also, note that since `$` will return a jQuery object, there is no need to pass `vid` to it again, which will be slower:

```
var dataid = vid.data('vid');
var dataalid = vid.data('alid');
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I learned more from your answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

trythis

```
 var vid=$('div#selected a');
 var dataid=$(vid).attr('data-vid');
 var dataalid=$(vid).attr('data-alid');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong selector for id.. and you don't need double `$(...)`
try this

```
var vid=$('div#selected a');
--------------^--- here this is id and not class 
var dataid=vid.data('vid');
-----------^-- here
var dataalid=vid.data('alid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, instead of '.' you have to use '#' because you are referring to an id and use `.attr()` to refer to your specific attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var vid=$('div#selected a');
    var dataalid = vid.attr('data-alid');
    var datavid = vid.attr('data-vid');
});
```